TatukGIS ASP.Net C#: Adding WMS Layers
WMS Layer not shown in TATUKGIS Viewer (Developer Kernel) on a ASP.Net C# page
Not sure whether someone can help me.
I'm trying to add a WMS Layer to a TatukGIS Viewer from the Developer Kernel. But nothing appears in the map. If I enter the same url in the free TatukGIS Viewer application, it works well.
GIS_MainViewer.ImageFormat = TGIS_ImageFormat.Png;
GIS_MainViewer.ClearMap();
GIS_MainViewer.SetCSByEPSG(4326);

lWMSLayer2 = new TGIS_LayerWMS();
lWMSLayer2.Path = @"https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=image/png&SERVICE=WMS";
lWMSLayer2.Name = "Open Streetmap Data";
lWMSLayer2.Active = true;
            
GIS_MainViewer.Add(lWMSLayer2);
lWMSLayer2.ZOrder = 99;

Very specific question, I'm sorry
